# Trying to extract xhr response but I keep getting a 422 error: unprocessable entity

Tags: python, urllib

I am trying to extract the xhr response but I keep getting a 422 error. My code is:

```
url = "https://www.website.com/users/12345/activities?limit=15&start_from_id=0&_=1211"
contents =  urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'content-type':'text/javascript', 'accept':'text/javascript'})
res = urllib.request.urlopen(contents).read()
```

and the output of

```
r = requests.get(url)
headers = r.request.headers
print(headers)
```

is `{'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.22.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}`

and in the network tab of the chrome inspect element window, the response headers content type is `text/javascript; charset=utf-8` and the request headers accept is `text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this a GET request?  You don't appear to be sending any data, so you shouldn't set "content-type" on the request.  Some websites only work with recognized User-Agents.

Comment: yes I had the content-type set in the request. I have taken that out. Thanks for pointing that out. Also, I set the user-agent header to the current chrome user agent but I'm still getting the same error. Any other thoughts?

Comment: If you make this same request with wget or curl, does it work?

Comment: I just tried both and I get the same error with either

Comment: Then it's possible the site requires a login cookie.  Is this a site you have to log in to?

Comment: No. I have successfully pulled from other api's on their website but this one seems to be giving me some trouble.

Comment: Also, @TimRoberts, forgot to mention (not sure if it helps or not), I can see the response just fine upon inspecting the xhr response in google chrome

Comment: I can pull from any api on the website that produces a json response but any that produces a javascript response causes problems

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks for your help. I was finally able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out by adding in all the request headers one by one. Finally the last one worked which was `x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest`